# Android: Call to Spring MVC Restful WebService

Tags: java, android, spring, web-services, rest

I have a **restful web service** which is written by using `spring`. Now I want to call it from my android application.

Unfortunately I am familiar with retrofit.

This is one of my method in restful web service.

```
import com.example.service.RosterDetailService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;    

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/roster")
public class RosterDetailManagement {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RosterDetailManagement.class);

    @Autowired
    private RosterDetailService rosterDetailService;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/details/getGuardRecords", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Map<Object, Object>> getRosterDetailsByGuardEmailAndType(@RequestBody ObjectNode params) {
        logger.info("-----------RosterDetailManagement, getRosterDetailsByGuardEmailAndType 1");
        Map<Object, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        String guardEmail = params.get("guardEmail").asText();
        String status = params.get("status").asText();

        return rosterDetailService.getRosterDetailsByGuardEmailAndType(guardEmail, status);
    }
}
```

Now I want detailed steps to call this restful web service in android.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: You mean to say you are **not** familiar with Retrofit?  If that's the case then have you gone through some tutorials?  What code do you have?  What isn't working?

Comment: @nasch : I said I am familiar with retrofit. I have a sample code. I will update my question.

Comment: If you're familiar with retrofit then what's the problem?